# Is there a !$ equivalent in powershell?

Tags: powershell, terminal

Is there a !$ equivalent in powershell? Essentially, I'd like to be able to use a command like

```
mv *.txt ~\Documents
```

And then be able to use something like

```
cd !$
```

And that should take me to the Documents folder specified in the previous command. I use it all the time in linux and it bugs me that it's not like that in powershell.

Thanks!

Edit: When using $$ I get the following error

```
PS C:\Users\josh.howard\Desktop\test> mv *.mp 'C:\Program Files\LANDesk\ManagementSuite\ldscan'

PS C:\Users\josh.howard\Desktop\test> cd $$
cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''C' does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd $$
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ('C:String) [Set-Location], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Comment: PowerShell has `$^`, which is essentially "final token of command line from previous command." Would this work for you?

Comment: From the looks of it $^ will actually give you the command itself. When I tested it, it tried to take me to a directory called mv and failed cause it's not there. Alternatively, when I use $$ it will give me the first character of the last argument in the previous command but it's only the first character.

Comment: The automatic variable documentation says that `$$` gives the last token of the previous command. I use it successfully quite often, so if this isn't working for you, a module may be interrupting it.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart From docs:  `$^` - Contains the first token in the last line received by the session. `$$` should be what the op is looking for. Just tried it now. Wonder if the tilde is messing with it.

Comment: `$$` is the only method I know of.  Easiest method would be to assign the destination to a variable and then set the location to the variable.  The object oriented nature of PowerShell makes `$$` of limited usefulness.  The PowerShell way of doing it would be something arcane like `mv .\*.txt ${env:USERPROFILE}\Documents -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectoryName -First 1 | ForEach-Object { cd $_ }`.

Comment: Hmm I've tried the $$ but I'm only getting the first character. I'll update the question with my error message.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell?

Comment: I'm using v4 @BaconBits

Comment: @b1ackjosh please post both exact commands (`$$` *and* the preceding command)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I just updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Does that mean it is having an issue since the string is quoted? `''C'`. I can replicate this with a quoted string.

Comment: I can confirm that `cd $$` throws an error when the last token is quoted.  Looks like a bug.

Comment: @BaconBits I wonder if this has already been reported as a bug then.

Comment: I looked through the microsoft connect stuff and it doesn't look like anyone's reported it. but I'm not seeing a place to file specific bugs for powershell in there either. edit: I take that back, I found the place to file, but it won't allow me to. Something must by wrong with my microsoft connect account.

Comment: Pretty sure the right place is https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell. Does not appear to be reported yet

Comment: So I tested this in windows 10 and it seems to work there, but not in version 4. So it seems to have been fixed as long as your on something newer than 4.

Comment: Looks like you have your answer then... and found and old bug possibly in the process.

Comment: Sorry yes, typo on my part `$$` is the one you're looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[about_automatic_variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847768.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) has the immediate answer to what you are looking for here.

> `$$`
>
> Contains the last token in the last line received by the session.

In practice this should have worked.

```
PS C:\Users\josh.howard\Desktop\test> mv *.mp 'C:\Program Files\LANDesk\ManagementSuite\ldscan'

PS C:\Users\josh.howard\Desktop\test> cd $$
```

However in your case there is a problem with the embedded quotes of the token.

> `cd : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''C' does not exist.`

I am able to replicate this issue using PowerShell v4. Normally when you sent a quoted string to a cmdlet like `Set-Location` the parser will consume the quotes then send the full path to the parameter `Path`. Using `$$` with your test case is actually sending the unescaped quoted string! That is why removing them make the process work.

```
cd ($$.Trim("'"))
```

[Bill Stewart has a process to address this issue as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35296330/3829407)

It is possible this has been addressed in v5 but I cannot confirm this exact situation.

> So I tested this in windows 10 and it seems to work there, but not in version 4. So it seems to have been fixed as long as your on something newer than 4.

Comment: If someone has more information please post an answer. I just wanted to get something logged for this one.

Comment: The `$$` variable is literally correct. It's returning the last token from the previous input, which might contain quotes. If I wanted to use this constantly with `Set-Location`, I would probably write a function to "de-quote" the string.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart `Set-Location` obviously works with quoted strings just fine. Just odd parsing issue when passed via `$$`. Oh... I get it now. $$ is essentially passing the quotes to `cd` and it is being interpreted as a literal path. When just typed out the quotes are consumed by the parser. Does that sound right?

Comment: Correct. `$$` will get the last token. This might include embedded quotes as a part of the string. This is a problem when passing to another command, as quotes are usually delimiters, not embedded in the string.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Thanks for the confirmation. I am going to revise my post to remove the "bug" references. This is working by design.

Comment: Correct, by design, and an implication of the difference between "quote as a delimiter" vs. "quote embedded in the string".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample `cd` function that works with `$$`:

```
function cd {
  param(
    [String] $path
  )
  Set-Location $path.Trim('"').Trim("'")
}
```